# Excel - Linking two sheets, when they share a common column

Tags: excel

Excel - Linking two sheets, when they share a common column.

Basically, I have some 6000 product IDs on spreadsheet 1 with their prices and description, and the same 6000 product IDs on spreadsheet 2, but with their barcodes.

Is there anyway I can have a 3rd spreadsheet, that automatically shows the ID, Price, description and Barcode when I enter values into either of the first two spreadsheets?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the third worksheet's A2, put,

```
=Sheet1!A2
```

In the third worksheet's B2, put,

```
=vlookup(A2, Sheet1!A:B, 2, false)
```

In the third worksheet's C2, put,

```
=vlookup(A2, Sheet2!A:B, 2, false)
```

Fill all three A2:C2 down to row 6000.

More on the [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) can be found clicking [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

Comment: Awesome! Seems to do the job. Just need to use this process on a dozen other columns! :P

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet 3 you can use the following formula's to pull across the data from Sheets 1 and 2.

```
=IF(Sheet1!A2="","",Sheet1!A2)
=IF(Sheet1!B2="","",Sheet1!B2)
=IF(Sheet1!C2="","",Sheet1!C2)
=IF(A2="","",INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet3!A2,Sheet2!$A:$A,0),1))
```

You will need to change the sheet names to match what you have within your workbook.

I have used an [IF statement](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), so that no values will be shown if there is not data within sheets 1 and 2; you will need to drag the formulas down as far as you believe there will be data (in case of extra data being added to sheets 1 and 2 in the future).

I have also used an [index](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/INDEX-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) [match](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a), as a pose to @Jeeped's vlookup.